# Samsung smartthings OAuth2.0 Virtual Switch

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, smartthings

I am developing a Samsung SmartThings virtual switch application with Google OAuth2.0 authentication. My setup involves fetching device details from a connector file into my app file through the /initiate-discovery endpoint.

However, the device details are not being populated as expected, with the discovery process logging an empty array for devices. Below are the relevant sections of my code and the output I'm receiving. I'm seeking guidance on why the device details from connector are not appearing in the discovery response.

Output received:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs6Qd.png)

App code snippet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7vrM.png)

Connector code snippet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7FPk.png)

I also manually added a test device to the discovery response in app to ensure that the view rendering logic works correctly, which it does. However, when attempting to add devices through connector, the array remains empty. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you